# \n is not working inside the array when I call the function

Tags: python

```
def question():

    question1 = [
        "what is  you name?:\n Where do you live? :"
    ]

    print(question1)


question()
```

`\n` is not breaking the line. When if I don't use function `\n` does it job(put the text in next line) , But I need it to be inside the function, please someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

`question1` is a Python list, and so `print(question1)` is printing the string representation of the list, which will not break at the newline, but instead show you the newline in the output as you're seeing:

```
['what is  you name?:\n Where do you live? :']
```

On the other hand, if you `print(question[0])`, you will get the desired result since you're printing the raw string:

```
what is  you name?:
 Where do you live? :
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a `list` here (`question1` is a `list` object), not a `str`. If you want to print that string within the array, index it like this

```python
question1 = [
    "what is  you name?:\n Where do you live? :"
]
# question1[0] means "first element of question1"
print(question1[0])
```

Also do you really need that `list` ? Why not directly using a string here ? Like this

```python
question1 = "what is  you name?:\n Where do you live? :"
print(question1)
```